# How to add digits within a string from user input

Tags: python, string

I'm still learning Python and I ran into a problem. My professor wants me to ask the user for input of a number with several digits with nothing separating them. Then, he wants me to write a program that would add those digits together and print the result. I can't do it because I don't understand how.

This is what I'm trying:

```
 inp = input("Please enter a number with several digits with nothing separating them: ")
 for number in inp:
       count += int(len[inp])
 print(count)
```

There are other ways I tried to do this, but it's just not working. What am I doing wrong? Exactly how should I do this? This is from Chapter 6 in "Python for Everybody" book.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to define `count` variable:

```py
count = 0
```

`input()` method returns a string without the trailing newline. You can iterate over characters in `inp` to sum up their numeric values:

```py
for n in inp:
    count += int(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `count` variable to store the sum of each iterable value

instead of `count+=int(list(inp))` you need to use `count+=number` as you are iterating the input string and already accessing each digit in for loop

```
inp = input("Please enter a number with several digits with nothing separating them: ")
count = 0
for number in inp:
    count += int(number)
print(count)
```

Comment: It worked! I realized why it didn't work before, because I didn't define a value for the variable "count" before I used it for a calculation, and didn't realize that "number" could've been any value that was input from the user and use that for the calculation. Thank you, I learned a lot from here.

Comment: The thing is, although this method worked, I am supposed to use the function "len" to access the length of the string and then add each character to the other within the string. I tried to do that but it does not work. I have to use "len" because my Professor asked for it, not because I did.

Comment: @AnaBaird you can use `for index in range(len(inp)): count+=int(inp[index])`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try in that way?

```
inp = input("Please enter a number with several digits with nothing separating them: ")
 count=0
 for number in inp:
     count += int(number)
 print(count)
```

Example if the user enter 25, the result should be 7, is it?